# Reading from a file and differentiating a question from an answer

Tags: c

I'm working on a university project that's a country guessing game. It uses a binary tree to make a guess, it should be able to learn new countries via the user adding a question when the guess is incorrect, and it’s meant to read from a file the questions and answers.

The problem lies here; running the code for the first time it works fine and you can play over and over again and it works well, but after ending the game and starting it up again where it reads from the text file created after the first playthrough, it treats every line as a question and only the last line as an answer. Then there's also the fact that each question should be treated as a node that leads to other questions or an answer and having it read the file and be able to make a node of all the questions and link them properly with the questions preceding and following it.

I tried giving the questions and answers the prefixes "Q: " and "A: " respectively and having it use that to differentiate the questions and answers.

Does anyone have any idea on what I can do so that when I load the file it makes the binary tree properly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 256

typedef struct TreeNode {
    char question[MAX_LENGTH];
    struct TreeNode* yes;
    struct TreeNode* no;
} TreeNode;

TreeNode* createNode(const char* question) {
    TreeNode* newNode = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    strncpy(newNode->question, question, MAX_LENGTH - 1);
    newNode->question[MAX_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';  // Ensure null-termination
    newNode->yes = NULL;
    newNode->no = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void saveTreeToFile(TreeNode* node, FILE* file) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    fprintf(file, "%s\n", node->question);
    saveTreeToFile(node->yes, file);
    saveTreeToFile(node->no, file);
}

TreeNode* loadTreeFromFile(FILE* file) {
    char question[MAX_LENGTH];

    if (fgets(question, MAX_LENGTH, file) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // Remove newline character if present
    size_t len = strlen(question);
    if (len > 0 && question[len - 1] == '\n') {
        question[len - 1] = '\0';
    }

    TreeNode* newNode = createNode(question);
    newNode->yes = loadTreeFromFile(file);
    newNode->no = loadTreeFromFile(file);

    return newNode;
}

void playGame(TreeNode* node) {
    char answer;

    // If it's a leaf node, make a guess
    if (node->yes == NULL && node->no == NULL) {
        printf("Is it %s? (y/n): ", node->question);
        scanf(" %c", &answer);

        if (answer == 'y') {
            printf("I guessed correctly!\n");
        } else {
            // Handle incorrect guess
            char userCountry[MAX_LENGTH];
            printf("I give up. What was the country you were thinking of? ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]", userCountry);

            char newQuestion[MAX_LENGTH];
            printf("What question should I have asked to distinguish %s from %s? ", node->question, userCountry);
            scanf(" %[^\n]", newQuestion);

            // Update the tree with the new information
            node->yes = createNode(userCountry);
            node->no = createNode(node->question);
            strncpy(node->question, newQuestion, MAX_LENGTH - 1);
            node->question[MAX_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';  // Ensure null-termination
        }
    } else {
        // Ask the question and continue playing if it's not a leaf node
        printf("%s (y/n): ", node->question);
        scanf(" %c", &answer);

        if (answer == 'y' && node->yes != NULL) {
            playGame(node->yes);
        } else if (answer == 'n' && node->no != NULL) {
            playGame(node->no);
        } else {
            // Invalid input, handle accordingly
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter 'y' or 'n'.\n");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Load or create the initial tree
    FILE* file = fopen("tree.txt", "r");
    TreeNode* root;
    if (file == NULL) {
        // If the file doesn't exist, create a new tree
        root = createNode("Is it a European country?");
        root->yes = createNode("France");
        root->no = createNode("Germany");
    } else {
        // Load the tree from the file
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);  // Reset file position to the beginning
        root = loadTreeFromFile(file);
        fclose(file);
    }

    char playAgain;
    do {
        playGame(root);
        printf("Would you like to play again? (y/n): ");
        scanf(" %c", &playAgain);
    } while (playAgain == 'y');

    // Save the tree to the file
    file = fopen("tree.txt", "w");
    if (file != NULL) {
        saveTreeToFile(root, file);
        fclose(file);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file for writing.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I wanted to know what I can do to have the code read the text file properly and make the binary tree.

Comment: First: look at the file that is written and check whether _you_ could differenciate between questions and answers and if so, _how_ you make the difference. Then try to put this into code. Btw: adding 'Q' or 'A' seems like a good idea. Your code doesn't show that